# Unknown “securenat” device showing up inside my network

Tags: networking

I’ve been noticing a strange device popping up inside my network from time to time. Its hostname is `securenat-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, where `xx` is its MAC address without colons.

I haven’t been able to figure out what it is or what it’s for, only that maybe it is related to something called `etherVPN`.

Can somebody please enlighten me? Furthermore, could this be a sign that something fishy is going on? This is a simple `/24` NAT network.

Comment: What protocol are you using to discover this device and learn its name?

Comment: It's my router's web config page, i think it's DHCP (since my PC, which has a static IP, does not appear there). This device pops up among the wired ones.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge, but a search pulled this up.https://www.google.ca/search?q=securenat&oq=securenat&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I did that too and came up with your same results but i know nothing about those microsoft technologies. If that's the case.

Comment: What are the first 3 octets of the MAC address. Pumping them into http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/ can give you a hint at the hardware vendor.

Comment: More than a year later this question has been rendered moot, since the probable source of the mysterious 'device' went away.

Answer (score 1):

If you have VPN enabled — like Softether — it shows up.

The SecureNAT function is a hitherto unknown innovative proprietary technology developed for the SoftEther VPN, the use of which enables the creation of a more secure network.

The SecureNAT function is broadly divided into two parts: the virtual NAT function and the virtual DHCP server function. The Virtual Hub Administrator can enable either or both the virtual NAT and virtual DHCP server when SecureNAT is enabled

Check this It worked for me:

[image: Click for image]

Comment: Downvoted as this technology has been arround a while and appears to tie in with Microsoft offerings - not a niche player. I have not researched in depth, but this answer seems to be a red herring.

Comment: It actually Worked Check the Image.....best i could do....sorry

Answer (score 0):

I've seen securenat in my wifi network too and had softether installed too at the time and i know what it did to me my router was able to record everything what was going on it showed bittor and sites it's even been too even PUBG which i never played and never been to tor before as far as i know it's illegal under the isp im in.

So this securenat in yours and my wifi network can be accessed by people using softether without you or me knowing and without u using softeither can still be accessed.

So far securenat in your wifi network is a way point to use u as a VPN in your network and your ip and could cause serious copyright infringement that u can be shutdown on your wifi network and won't be good at all for those actually using it u may be caught in the mix without u knowing and it's not your fault.

I do remember i was able to access a spectrum network while i was with ATT while using softether and it didn't last too long probably cause it had multiple copyright infrigement so it was shutdown or suspended.

And last you should definitely uninstall softeither software and try to get rid of it and use a paid vpn like PIA VPN and vanish or vyper VPN and do not use soft either a paid VPN is better so something like this does not happen to u like it did to me 3 different times.

Hopefully this explains what Securenat does in your wifi network. that made me come here and tell u what exactly happen

Comment: This should be verified by someone. It doesn't make sense for VPN traffic to be randomly routed through other clients' computers unencrypted. Either it's absurdly incompetent or untrue.